# Checking values between select values not giving proper result

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to compare the value of many select values and interchange them when they are same as I have tried in my code,

```
function OnChangeSelection(selection,selectid)
{
    var count=1;
    for(var j=5;j<=14;j++)
    {
        var c_id= "Numbering"+count;
        if (document.getElementById(selectid).value == document.getElementById(c_id).value) 
        {
            alert(c_id);
        }
        count++
    }
}
```

in this code I am getting perametera "selection is the value changed on selection " and "selectid" is the id of the select tag" so I wanna compare it in loop because I have 10 select and matching it via its id that would I generate by conacating Numbering+count and when it match it with another select value it prints that select id but issue is that it is printing the id of the another select and also the id of the select from which I am comparing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're comparing your element with itself at some point. Put some condition to skip self comparing:

```
function OnChangeSelection(selection,selectid)
{
    var count=1;
    for(var j=5;j<=14;j++)
    {
        var c_id= "Numbering"+count;
        if (c_id == selectid) {count++;continue;}
        if (document.getElementById(selectid).value == document.getElementById(c_id).value) 
        {
            alert(c_id);
        }
        count++
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Biaib how would i interchang there values too? when this condition gets true so it will swap there values ??

Comment: @SyedRaza sorry but I don't get what you mean by 'interchange' ? why would you want to swap equal values ? PS: maybe some HTML code, with some Before/After states would help.

Comment: yes i wanna interchange them like "  if (document.getElementById(selectid).value == document.getElementById(c_id).value) 
        {
temp=document.getElementById(c_id).value;
 document.getElementById(c_id).value=document.getElementById(selectid).value;
//alert(document.getElementById(selectid).value);
        }"

Comment: are you aware this will change nothing at all?

Answer (score -2):

You get the ID of the element selectid because in your iteration over all selects you compare it with itself. What is the value of the other select that is printed falsely? Try to change == to === and thus avoid implicit conversion.

Comment: ,For your Information,`==` is not assignment operator that implicitly does the conversion in JS, the only difference between `==`  and `===` is that the latter checks the type also.

Comment: Exactly what I said. == does a conversion to a common type and afterwards it compares, while === compares right away and bails out on type mismatch

Comment: True, === could be considered redundant when comparing values of select elements. But the fact that above code compares the same element with itself once is correct nonetheless